# Add-on for Internet explorer to see the file upload progress

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is IE able to show the progress of a file upload? Is there any plugin for IE which can provide this functionality?

Comment: Do you mean "download"?

Comment: @Denis: I'm sure he means 'upload'.